# .NET Web application that can be accessed from mobile device

Tags: language-agnostic

I am planning on developing .NET web application which also will be accessed from mobile device. I am thinking to create two separate projects, one for web site and one mobile device so that upon detecting whether users are accessing the web site either from computer or mobile device, start appropriate project (web site version or mobile version).  So for example, if users are accessing the web site from computer, it will show full screens (with all the functionalities).  And, if users are accessing the web site from mobile device, show screens with minimal controls.
Or, is there any other better design which to develop .NET Web application that can be accessed from mobile device?
Another question is that how do I detect whether users are accessing the web site from computer or mobile device in .NET web application?

Any suggestion or help would be appreciate it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered ASP.NET MVC?

Scott Hanselman did a session on ASP.NET MVC and mobile browser detection at MIX 09. [This](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx) blog entry that he did gives a good rundown.

He also talks about some code he was given that will help do the redirection based on the browser version.

I'm sure ASP.NET MVC 2 has even more goodies.

Good Luck,

Patrick

Comment: Looks like alehandrobog beat me to it - similar take on the same topic - Hanselman Rocks!

Answer (score 2):

Ther is a very good tutorial that show you how to do this with mvc. Check it out [ASP.NET MVC Videos](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/creating-nerddinnercom-with-microsoft-aspnet-model-view-controller-mvc), its totorial to create a complete app and they mention in one section how display content depending on what mobile phone the user is using